# Cannot type in an input box in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I cannot input anything in the input box.

Element:

```
<input id="cardnumber" autocomplete="cc-number" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="0000 0000 0000 0000" data-encrypted-name="number" aria-placeholder="" aria-describedby="cardnumber-error">
```

My code:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[1]/div/input"))).send_keys(ccnum)
```

What should I do? I get no warning. I obviously log in the account and then try this.

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: It's the spotify checkout for trial page.

Comment: OK, can you share a link?

Comment: Yeah, the link is: https://www.spotify.com/us/purchase/offer/default-trial-1m/?country=US

Comment: That link is behind a login. Try changing the locator to `element_to_be_clickable`. Also check if element is in an iframe, or in a shadow root. Try clicking in that field before sending keys to it. Finally, try doing it with Javascript: `browser.execute_script(...)`

Comment: I have 0 idea how to do that, could you help me? Also I log in the account then I try to type something there.